# Export Voronoi Data?

Tags: export

I have a Voronoi Diagram (VoronoiDiagram/DiagramPlot) in Mathematica - and I need to export it to something I can import into ArcGIS.

I'll settle for any sort of data/vector-based (non-raster) format. Obviously a BMP isn't going to work - I need the actual vector data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First take a look at [**Vector Graphics Formats**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html). This is an easy way to make Voronoi diagram

```
vd = ListDensityPlot[pts = RandomReal[1, {150, 3}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> (White &), Frame -> False,
   BoundaryStyle -> Black, Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]}]
```

[image]

These are some vector formats in Mathematica:

```
Export["tst." <> #, vd] & /@ {"svg", "wmf", "emf", "eps", "pdf", "dxf"}
{"tst.svg", "tst.wmf", "tst.emf", "tst.eps", "tst.pdf", "tst.dxf"}
```

For .PDF you may have to look into option `"AllowRasterization"->False` see [**details here**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PDF.html).

Comment: That worked as far as getting an SVG file out the other end... and the SVG file does contain a (correct) graphical representation of the Voronoi - however, I haven't confirmed yet that the actual data I need is still available in the SVG... we're looking into it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve please see other formats I added.

Comment: The DXF format seems to give me what I need. You didn't list that one, but, it's all the same. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Vitaliy I guess it can hold 3D graphics too, but personally I have only used it for 2D.  It does seem that if you re-import it, it gives you a `Graphics3D` object.  But Illustrator (a 2D vector editor) can open the exported DXF.

Comment: @Vitaliy I can export without an error on OS X, but please note that the extension is DXF, not DFX